# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration for facebook

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I have gone through the same question links on the site and still I am unable to get answer for this question. I have registered an API, checked URL for site. Its exact location of file which I am executing. The OAuth is performed and I also get login screen. But when I try logging the error appears. I am still trying to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: What URL are you trying to specify?

Comment: I specified this URL: http://my_domain/folder/facebook/fb_login.php